# Blender render background image distorted

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, image

I am trying to add an image as render background in 2.75, using Blender Render, not Cycles. I add a world texture, mapping set to "view". What I want is an image mapped 1:1 to the rendered background, meaning when I render the same dimensions as the input image, I want to get the same image as render output. What I get is an image with a pillow distortion, which amount depends heavily on the focal length/field of view of the camera:

[image: distorted render]

(This uses a rectangular grid as input)

Looks like some kind of spherical projection to me, but I set mapping coordinates to "view". I remember this working in previous Blender versions without having to use the compositor, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check "Paper sky" in the World Panel

[image]